# Sympa sending problems with attachments

Tags: sympa

I have set up a Sympa list serv server and everything is working fine for the most part. One issue that I am running into is sending files over ~580 KB in size (just a normal .txt file) are not going through. I am getting the following error.

> Impossible to distribute your message
>   for list 'list-name' because of an
>   internal server error.

I have verified that my "Maximum message size (max_size)" setting in Sympa is get to 5 MB so that shouldn't be the problem. If I try sending the same .txt file after taking out a few lines, and the file size is ~530 KB, then it works just fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have some interesting logs in Sympa ?

Comment: Nothing that's really jumping out to why that error is occurring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it fixed.

It was a problem with the database not being able to handle the packet size. I had to manually edit the /etc/my.cnf file and bump up the max_allowed_packets size and then restart mysqld.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this has something to do with php settings variables **upload_max_filesize** and **memory_limitphp**. They're normally somewhere in php.ini, depending on your OS and Webserver.

Comment: Sympa is written in Perl, not PHP. I don't know anything about upload limits in Perl, but I'd be willing to guess you're right about there being an upload size limit somewhere.

Comment: Oh, hmm, you're right, I'm confusing sympa and phplist.

Comment: It could be, but the only real "max file size limit" setting I see is the one I mentioned in the original post and it is set to 5 MB. The entire email including the .txt file attachment is less than 1 MB.